# Passar um parâmetro javascript em meio a um append

Tags: javascript, html

Sem muita enrolação, estou preso no seguinte problema:

Tenho o seguinte código JS:

```
data.forEach(function(item) {
        $("#bodyTabelaClientes").append(
            "<tr><td style = 'text-align: center'>" + item.nome 
            + "</td> <td style = 'text-align: center'> " + item.telefone 
            + "</td> <td style = 'text-align: center'> " + item.cep 
            + "</td> <td style = 'text-align: center'>" + item.endereco 
            + "</td> <td style = 'text-align: center'><button class = 'btn btn-success btnSelecionarCliente'  onclick='selecionarCliente("+item+")'>Selecionar</button></tr>");
    });
```

O meu problema está no botão dentro do append, eu preciso passar esse parâmetro 'item' como parâmetro pra outra função, pra pegar os dados desse item e fazer algo com eles, porém, ao clicar, o console acusa

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

com uma página em branco. Acredito que seja algum erro com as aspas, mas não consegui identificar, alguém tem alguma ideia do que fazer? Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não vai conseguir fazer com que o HTML passe para a função um objeto inteiro, eu sugiro que você passe como argumento o objeto completo em formato de texto.

**Exemplo**

```js
var data = [{
  nome: 'Lucas',
  telefone: '12',
  cep: '123',
  endereco: '123'
}]
data.forEach(function(item) {
  $("#bodyTabelaClientes").append(
    "<tr><td style = 'text-align: center'>" + item.nome +
    "</td> <td style = 'text-align: center'> " + item.telefone +
    "</td> <td style = 'text-align: center'> " + item.cep +
    "</td> <td style = 'text-align: center'>" + item.endereco +
    "</td> <td style = 'text-align: center'><button class = 'btn btn-success btnSelecionarCliente'  onclick='selecionarCliente(\"" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(item)) + "\");'>Selecionar</button></tr>");
});

function selecionarCliente(item) {
  var objeto = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(item));
  console.log(objeto);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id="bodyTabelaClientes">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Se somente converter o objeto para string usando `stringify`, haverá problema com escapes, por esse motivo usei [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) para que a string que será enviada como argumento seja codificada; então na função que será chamada usei o [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent), que irá converter para o texto novamente, e então `JSON.parse` para voltar para objeto.

Comment: Valeu demais, funcionou perfeitamente e a explicação no final também fez a diferença. Obrigado.